# Writing a custom http server, does supporting AJAX require extra code over HTTP GET?

Tags: c, ajax, http

I have to write a very lightweight server that can run on an embedded system processor in C.

I plan on only supporting GET requests with it. Most of the content will be static, but they will be generated by C CGI files (yes, I know, this is painful. But we only have C at our disposal).

Will I be able to support AJAX GET requests? I don't know if special server side code is required to handle them. I feel like AJAX is all client side.

Comment: Is it too much to try to cross compile node.js ?

Comment: Such a server already exists for the Arduino platform, I believe. You might want to check it out.

Comment: You might look at Luvit, a Lua-based nodejs clone that they claim runs on raspberry pi.  http://luvit.io/

Comment: Can you provide any more info on your HW platform?  How memory constrained are you?

Answer (score 2):

The question you should ask yourself is why do you need to write a custom HTTP server at all. Research existing solutions to see whether or not they serve your needs. There are several lightweight HTTP servers that you may be able to port to your embedded system, assuming you have some kind of POSIX layer to program on:

- [Libmicrohttpd](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/):

  > GNU libmicrohttpd is a small C library that is supposed to make it easy to run an HTTP server as part of another application. GNU GNU Libmicrohttpd is free software and part of the GNU project.
- [lightttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/):

  > Security, speed, compliance, and flexibility -- all of these describe lighttpd (pron. lighty) which is rapidly redefining efficiency of a webserver; as it is designed and optimized for high performance environments. ... it's Open Source licensed under the revised BSD license.
- [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/):

  > nginx [engine x] is an HTTP and reverse proxy server, as well as a mail proxy server, written by Igor Sysoev. ... Here are some of the success stories: Netflix, Wordpress.com, FastMail.FM. ... The sources and documentation are distributed under the 2-clause BSD-like license.
- [thttpd](http://acme.com/software/thttpd/):

  > thttpd is a simple, small, fast, and secure HTTP server. It doesn't have a lot of special features, but it suffices for most uses of the web, it's about as fast as the best full-featured servers (Apache, NCSA Netscape), and it has one extremely useful feature (URL-traffic-based throttling) that no other server currently has.

The reason to wave you away from implementing your own if possible is because AJAX largely relies on HTTP/1.1 features to be able to provide a quality user experience, and implementing all of HTTP/1.1 from scratch is a rather daunting task that will likely take many development iterations before the server is stable and performant enough to be a satisfactory product.

Comment: I would add [thttpd](http://acme.com/software/thttpd/) to that list.  It's the smallest / lightest I'm aware of that still provides a reasonably level of HTTP 1.1 compliance and decent feature set.

Comment: I was looking deeper into the hardware specs. I don't think that we have the luxury of POSIX. Now, say that we weren't to use AJAX, can we still send GET requests and get a response, and update a DIV tag, via javascript? If so, can you point me to a tutorial on how to do so? I feel that ajax is just a fancy browser-supported feature that sends GET requests. If i were to write a simple server that supports GET, wouldn't that be enough? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @de1337ed: If you don't have POSIX out of the box, it may be worth it to shell out the bucks to get a port of a POSIX system ported to your platform. This just makes features so much easier to develop, debug, and deploy, you and your employer will definitely see the investment pay dividends. You don't provide many details about your HTML application, so it is hard to say what will suffice. If you are providing real time graphs, for instance, a non HTTP/1.1 implementation will not really deliver a very satisfying experience.

Answer (score 1):

The interesting parts of AJAX happens entirely on the client side.  For those who aren't aware, AJAX stands for 'Asyncronous Javascript And XML', meaning that the requests will be made via javascript asynchronously from the client's perspective.  The XML part is misleading since these are normal HTTP requests, and the response can contain anything.

As far as your server is concerned, you will handle those requests EXACTLY the same as you would handle any other request.  No special code, no special servelets, etc.  There is nothing that makes a request 'AJAX' from your server's perspective, so treat it like you would any other.

Also, I hope the project is going well and good luck.  Too many people shy away from interesting challenges like these because they are difficult, or it seems like there is an easy out.

Answer (score -1):

AJAX is fine, it's just GET (or occasionally POST) requests which are formatted exactly the same on the server side.

The difference on the server is, they'll typically go to a different "servlet" (or method in your C code) to be answered.

Typically, the answer may be XML, JSON (serialized data for Javascript) or perhaps an HTML fragment (without  or  tags, just the content of a  or something.). Or it could just be a 200 OO response indicating "success".

On the browser side, AJAX is requested & used from Javascript *within* a page;  with the results then either pasted into the DOM via `innerHtml` (for HTML fragments), or built into the DOM via Javascript (for JSON). The second option is less performant.

Your first typical use-case might well be an autocomplete for a search-box, or something like that.

---

The big issue with HTTP servers is, they're expected to be reliable. C is not a great language to deliver 24-7 reliable software in.

Java for me, was a great leap forward in that you could safely do strings & log what your darn program was doing -- which I feel is a minimum requirement for quality engineering & debuggability. Good luck!

Comment: C is not a reliable language ? anything is based on C, the linux kernel runs for months without a problem ... what is your problem with the C language exactly ?

Comment: I used to write high-reliability software in C and C++. Including kernel-level stuff. The main problem is the difficulty of building strings or doing diagnostic logging safely, without the danger of causing buffer overruns or secondary failures. **Code without logging is not engineering.**

Comment: @user2485710 I suppose you never heard that C-code Windows device drivers are still showing up hidden bugs & race conditions, despite years of "debugging"? +1 on your opinion of C for reliability.  http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/terminator/eurosys.pdf

Comment: @ThomasW Race conditions are not a question of the language actually. In general I think it's more the (call it naive) programmer than the language itself that impairs reliability. But you are right. C doesn't help you against mistakes.

Comment: Building strings and logging is difficult?  How is it different than any other memory management task?

Comment: @A.R. From my perspective, logging program activity is a fundamental of software _engineering_ as opposed to _cowboy coding_. Error logging approaches in C typically take either of two approaches: 1) allocate & grow a buffer for the message, as it's built. 2) allocate a buffer with a fixed maximum. Now, I'm fundamentally concerned by error-logging which may itself be a source of error.. buffer overflows or OOM. These concerns are especially acute with web requests/ XML, which may be quite arbitrarily large, in a constrained embedded environment. Now do you mind changing it to an upvote?

Comment: If you have a constrained environment, then you don't have the luxury of creating arbitrarily large logs.  You certainly don't have the luxury of using java either.

Comment: Nor really the luxury of safely & reliability with arbitrarily large requests/ data, which HTTP Requests and AJAX (as XML/JSON) often tend to expose. Which is why I wished him _good luck_. Now lighten up & stop being such a grump, @A.R.